# fread can't read string value of a struct from a binary file in C

Tags: c, fread

I want to return a pointer to the head structure of linked list in following function but since my fread can't read struct's string, I have to malloc some variables and point newheader->name string to it. In following function if I free my temporary variables then returned new header only prints null values and If I don't then I get memory leaks but function works fine. I want to be able to return head of a complete linked list not null value.

```
struct head *read_strings(char *file) {
    FILE *my_file;
    struct head * newheader = NULL;
    char *str = NULL; 
    newheader = buildhead();

    int len, lenStr, lenTotal = 0;
    printf("\n\n");
    my_file = fopen(filename, "rb"); 
    if (my_file == NULL) {
        printf("error\n");
    }
    fread(&len,sizeof(int),1, my_file);
    newheader->name = malloc(len);
    fread(newheader->name,sizeof(char),len, my_file);
    fread(&newheader->length,sizeof(int),1, my_file);

    if (newheader->length != 0) {
        if (newheader->length == lenTotal) {
            fread(&lenStr,sizeof(int),1, my_file);
            str = malloc(lenStr); //char *str = malloc(lenStr);
            fread(str,sizeof(char),lenStr, my_file);
            create_string(newheader, str);
            lenTotal += lenStr;
            str = NULL; //free(str);
        }
        else {
            while (newheader->length != lenTotal) {
                fread(&lenStr,sizeof(int),1, my_file);
                str = malloc(lenStr); //char *str = malloc(lenStr);
                fread(str,sizeof(char),lenStr, my_file);
                create_string(newheader, str);
                lenTotal += lenStr;
                str = NULL; //free(str);
            }
        }
    }

    printString(newheader);
    fclose(my_file);
    free(str);
    //if i free newheader->name here then I get no memory leaks
    //free(newheader->name);
    freeStructure(newheader);
    return newheader;
}
```

I am required to read strings from binary file and store them into struct. But I can't store values directly to string variable of struct unless I malloc a new string and point to it. You can see in above code that I am able to read newheader->length from fread but not newheader->name. I tried to put fread results in a string array but got segmentation fault.

This is how my binary file looks like. It has null terminator after every string and int.

```
0000000 021  \0  \0  \0   i   t       i   s       a       g   o   o   d
0000020       d   a   y  \0   R  \0  \0  \0   #  \0  \0  \0   I   t    
0000040   w   a   s       t   h   e       b   e   s   t       o   f    
0000060   o   y   e       h   o   y   e       t   i   m   e   s   .  \0
0000100 034  \0  \0  \0   I   t       w   a   s       t   h   e       b
0000120   l   u   r   s   t       o   f       t   i   m   e   s   .  \0
0000140  \a  \0  \0  \0   m   o   n   k   e   y  \0 006  \0  \0  \0   p
0000160   a   n   d   a  \0 006  \0  \0  \0   s   h   i   f   u  \0
0000177
```

If I free newheader->name in the my freestruct() function then I get following error

```
*** Error in `./test': munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer:
0x000000000040133e *** Aborted.
```

if don't free it then I lose 17 bytes in 1 block.

```
==24169== HEAP SUMMARY:
==24169==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==24169==   total heap usage: 5 allocs, 6 frees, 1,201 bytes allocated
==24169== 
==24169== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==24169== 
==24169== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from0)
==24169== 
==24169== 1 errors in context 1 of 1:
==24169== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==24169==    at 0x4C29E90: free (in
/usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==24169==    by 0x401298: freestruct (A1.c:267)
==24169==    by 0x400F8A: write_strings (A1.c:189)
==24169==    by 0x400840: main (test.c:25)
==24169==  Address 0x40133e is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently)
free'd
==24169== 
==24169== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from0)
```

This is small piece of code from my freestruct() function

```
if (header->next == NULL) {
    header->length = 0;
    free(header->name);
    free(header);
}
```

After writing string to binary file, I freed the whole structure and then created again in read_strings function

Edit: If I free newheader->name inside readString function then I get no memory leaks but I want to be return newheader to main and call printString and freestruct after that.

I apologize for my bad grammar.

Comment: Use a debugger to step through the code line by line while monitoring variables and their values. Also, you use a function called `setName`, what does it do? And what does `getName` do? Do you need to set the structures `name` member *twice*?

Comment: And an unrelated query, do the string (and its length) in the file contain the string terminator?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg setname just assigns any string sent to it, to header->name and getname just returns that

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your `setName` and `getName` functions correctly, then these three lines are the problem:

```
...
setName(newheader, name);
newheader->name = getName(newheader);
...
free(name);
```

First of all the two first lines do the same thing, but that's not problematic, just redundant. It's the last line there that causes the problem.

You make `newheader->name` point to the same memory that `name` points to. After the assignment both pointers are pointing to the same memory. Then you free the memory. That makes both pointers invalid.

You either need to *duplicate* (with e.g. the non-standard but common `strdup` function). Or not free the memory.

---

Lets see if I can make it clearer...

You have a variable `name` for which you allocate memory. It will look something like this:

```
+------+     +---------------------+
| name | --> | memory for the name |
+------+     +---------------------+
```

What the assignment

```
newheader->name = name;
```

actually does is just copy the *pointer*, not the memory it points to. So after the assignment you have something like this:

```
+------+
| name | ------------\
+------+              \    +---------------------+
                       >-> | memory for the name |
+-----------------+   /    +---------------------+
| newheader->name | -/
+-----------------+
```

You now have two variables pointing to the same memory.

Then you do

```
free(name);
```

This free's the memory, but remember that we have *two* variable pointing to the same memory. Now it looks like

```
+------+
| name | -------------> ?
+------+           

+-----------------+
| newheader->name | --> ?
+-----------------+
```

So whenever you try to access `newheader->name` you will try to access the now free'd memory, and you will have *undefined behavior*.

Comment: setName and getName are just help functions in linked list. I can replace them with newheader->name  = name; 
I tried using strcpy(newheader->name, name); but that also gave me seg fault

Comment: @samadbond Updated my answer. Hope it makes it clearer.

Comment: thanks for detailed explanation. I understand whats happening but I can't come up with any other way to read string from binary file using fread. At the end of the function I am required to return header to the linked list. Whats any other solution for adding string to newheader->name

Comment: @samadbond You probably read the string fine (use a debugger to find out, or just print it after you read it). But what you should *not* do is free the memory the string is stored in, you need to keep it and then free it when you free the whole structure.

Comment: **if (header->next == NULL) {header->length = 0;
        header->name = NULL;
        free(header->name);
        free(header);
    }**

Comment: above is small part of my freestruct() function. I still get 17 bytes lost in 1 block when run against valgrind

Comment: @samadbond Because you set `header->name` to `NULL` *before* you call `free`. Change the order.

Comment: when I change the order I get error saying *** Error in `./test': munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer: 0x000000000040133e ***
Aborted.

Comment: in valgring it says 5 allocs and 6 frees

Comment: @samadbond And you ***don't*** do `free(name)` anymore? What else do Valgrind tell you? Please update your question with the Valgrind output.